# How to turn pandas dataframe row into ordereddict fast

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ordereddictionary

Looking for a fast way to get a row in a pandas dataframe into a ordered dict with out using list. List are fine but with large data sets will take to long. I am using fiona GIS reader and the rows are ordereddicts with the schema giving the data type. I use pandas to join data. I many cases the rows will have different types so I was thinking turning into a numpy array with type string might do the trick.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't just do an apply (since it fits it back to a DataFrame):

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [3]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [4]: df.apply(OrderedDict)
Out[4]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

But you can use a list comprehension with [iterrows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
In [5]: [OrderedDict(row) for i, row in df.iterrows()]
Out[5]: [OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)]), OrderedDict([('a', 3), ('b', 4)])]
```

If it was possible to use a generator, rather than a list, to whatever you were working with this will usually be more efficient:

```
In [6]: (OrderedDict(row) for i, row in df.iterrows())
Out[6]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10466da50>
```

Comment: Obsoleted by the to_dict `into` keyword argument in the answer from @jezrael

Answer (score 23):

This is implemented in `pandas 0.21.0+` in function [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with parameter `into`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b'])
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4

d = df.to_dict(into=OrderedDict, orient='index')
print (d)
OrderedDict([(0, OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])), (1, OrderedDict([('a', 3), ('b', 4)]))])
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: this is a great answer.. can we edit it to import ordered dict so the code runs?

add:

`from collections import OrderedDict`