# Pandas: DataFrame row into variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `DataFrame`:

```
x = DataFrame({
        "x" : [1,2,3],
        "y" : [4,5,6],
        "z" : [7,8,9]
    })
```

I want to retrieve the row where `x` equals `1`, and store the `y` and `z` values there in variables with the same name.

I'm able to do this, but I had to resort to `itertuples()` and a bunch of other steps:

```
_, y, z = next(x.loc[x.x == 1, ["y", "z"]].itertuples())
```

Is there a cleaner/preferred way of doing this?  [This answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18996948/717481) would suggest no, but I just wanted to check.

Comment: `_, y, z = x.query('x==1').values.tolist()[0]` or `_, y, z = x[x.x.eq(1)].values.tolist()[0]`?

Comment: But, why do you want to store them like variables and not as dict? `x[x.x.eq(1)].iloc[0].to_dict()`